# Add item to collection of selected item of listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I have two listboxes in my window. The first listbox "all_styles" shows the styles in a collection, the second listbox "Style_subjects" shows the subjects in a collection of the selected style in the first listbox. So far so good!

I want to introduce a button to add a new subject to current selected style. Is there a way to bind the button to the selected style of the listbox and to add a new subject to the binded selection? Here is my current code:

xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="QuickSlide_2._0.Window1"
    x:Name="load_style"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Load_style" Height="300" Width="300" MinHeight="720" MinWidth="1280" WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" Background="#B0000000" AllowDrop="True" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" ShowInTaskbar="False">
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Close" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1081,65,0,0" Name="close" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Click="close_Click" />
    <Button Content="New style" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="326,65,0,0" Name="New_style" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Click="New_style_Click"/>
    <Button Content="New subject" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="704,65,0,0" Name="New_subject" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Click="New_subject_Click" />
    <ListBox Height="146" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="74,111,0,0" x:Name="all_styles" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="209" ItemsSource="{Binding styles, ElementName=load_style}" SelectedIndex="0">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <ListBox Height="314" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="74,297,0,0" Name="Style_subjects" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="209" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.subjects, ElementName=all_styles}" SelectedIndex="0">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

and the code:

```
public class subject
{
    public string name {get; set;}
    public subject(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}


public class style
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<subject> subjects {get; set;}

    public style(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
        subjects = new ObservableCollection<subject>();
    }
}


public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<style> styles {get; set;}
    public Window1()
    {
        styles = new ObservableCollection<style>();
        InitializeComponent();

        styles.Add(new style("test"));
        styles[0].subjects.Add(new subject("item"));
   }

    private void close_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void New_style_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        styles.Add(new style("new_style"));           
    }

    private void New_subject_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // this next line is probably not correct....
        this.add(new subject("new_subject"));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
((style)this.all_styles.SelectedItem).Add(new subject("item"));
```